# Are droids sentient or not?

Tags: star-wars, droids

In *Star Wars*, droids are frequently treated as second-class citizens by most of the galaxy. Even your working class people don't treat them with respect (see Owen Lars, *A New Hope*). Why is this? I mean, you could say that it's because they're man-made beings, but various canon sources have shown that they seem to be no less sentient than an organic being. Various examples of this include (and this barely begins to cover it):

- *Star Wars Rebels* - C1-10P (Chopper) reluctantly accompanies Ezra Bridger to Tatooine and through the desert.
- *The Legends of Luke Skywalker* - One story is told from a worker droid's point of view, as it is captured and reprogrammed into a cruel enforcer, feeling regret as it is forced to abuse others of its kind and inflict pain while being powerless to stop it.
- *From a Certain Point of View* - R5-D4 finds enough *emotion* (hope) to damage his motivator and allow R2-D2 to come into the possession of Luke Skywalker and save the galaxy.

All of these examples that I just listed are canon. Now, with thoughts and feelings such as this, why are droids not considered sentient?

Comment: *Well, if droids could think, there'd be none of us here, would there?*

Comment: [Fantastic Racism](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FantasticRacism).  ObWarning: TV Tropes.

Comment: You said: "Treated as second-class citizens." I thought: "Huh? They weren't citizens at all; they were simply *property* to be bought and sold at the drop of a hat!" (Heck, we saw that happen to R2-D2 and C-3PO early on in the first film.)

Comment: ... of course, Anakin and his mother were property too.  It isn't *just* droids, though IIRC that varies from planet to planet.

Comment: droids are "acceptable" slaves in the republic. IIRC there was going to be a bit about droid rebellion in the original SW script, which was removed. basically seems that yes, SW droids are sentient, but the society has not yet accepted them as people / still consider them slaves/property etc.

Comment: Okay, this is something that probably bothers only me, but do you mean sentient or sapient? Because there's a pretty big difference and while normally you can use them interchangeably for organic races (although you probably shouldn't), it just gets even more confusing when you add "made" life into the mix. I'd think it's pretty easy to argue that the droids are sentient, but as far as whether they are considered sapient goes (because it's pretty obvious that they are), that's an entirely different story, and I think your real question.

Comment: I think the next Star Wars movie should be "The Droid Rebellion". :-)
More seriously, what's left of the Resistance at the end of The Last Jedi could gain traction by guaranteeing droids citizen rights if enough choose to join their cause.

Comment: Please change either the headline or the question asked in the post, for the question of droids being sentient is not necessarily connected to the way they are treated. A being can be sentient and considered as such but still be treated 'second-class'.

Comment: Because "Star Wars: Measure of a Man" never aired.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## *TL;DR*

In my opinion, based on the evidence we are given:

- Are droids *sentient*? **Yes.**
- Are droids *sapient*? **Also, yes.**
- Are droids *conscious*/*self-aware*? **Again, I say yes.**

---

## FULL EXPLANATION/BREAKDOWN

### ARE DROIDS *SENTIENT*?

To the specific question asked, "are **[droids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Droid)** sentient", according to [the definition from Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/sentient), the answer is undoubtedly, "yes".

> **sentient** *adjective*
> /ˈsɛnʃənt/
> able to see or feel things through the senses

Here are some "examples" of a droid's basic sentience:

- **Sight:** Droids have photoreceptors that are capable of perceiving and processing visual stimuli from their environment, which they use for navigation, decision making, and various other tasks.
- **Hearing:** Droids also have receptors for processing audio input/commands from their "organic overlords".
- **Touch:** Some (*most?*) droids clearly have some sort of tactile sense that prevents them from accidentally crushing something they may be attempting to grasp, as well as, I would deduce, identify when there is some sort of physical obstacle preventing them from proceeding (amongst other behaviors).
- **Smell:** Some droids, at least, have [olfactory receptors](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Olfactory_sensor) in order to analyze the chemical composition of the air around them.
- **Taste:** While there's not much information available for droids with taste receptors in the current canon, the [SE4 Series Protocol Droid (SE4 servant droid)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/SE4_servant_droid) from various mentions in Legends was fitted with a taste bud on the lining of the left index finger.

Okay, so the last two are, admittedly, a *bit* of a stretch but, even without them, we see that droids are clearly "*able to see or feel things through (albeit, artificially created) senses*". This simple definition does not imply any inherent "understanding" of their surroundings or any deeper awareness of what those senses "mean" beyond base-level, instinctual (organic), or pre-programmed (artificial) responses to the appropriate stimuli.

In short, sentience is strictly the ability to perceive ones' surroundings. Any living thing that has some degree of consciousness is sentient, including insects, lizards, dogs, dolphins, and human beings. Using this definition, droids are clearly *at least* sentient.

### ARE DROIDS *SAPIENT*?

In my opinion, the next logical question in this line of thought is, "are droids ***sapient***?" The [Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/sapient) are a little less "on the nose" with this one:

> **sapient** *adjective*
> /ˈseɪpiənt/
> having great intelligence or knowledge

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sapient) gets a little closer:

> - intelligent; able to think
> - wise

Additionally, as most dictionaries do, it also lists a definition of "*relating to the human species Homo sapiens*", but we're talking about droids here and, since this ("*alternate*") definition would immediately and completely nullify the discussion, we'll put that one aside for our purposes here.

A more complete definition of sapient can be found in the article, [Sentience vs. Sapience](https://grammarist.com/usage/sentience-vs-sapience/) on Grammarist. In this definition (*emphasis mine*):

> Sapience means the *ability to think*, the *capacity* for intelligence, the ability to *acquire* wisdom.

This goes far beyond the sentient ability to simply *perceive* their surroundings. This means that they can interact with that environment in "meaningful" ways. They may, in some cases, even be able to manipulate their circumstances through the use of intelligent analysis of the stimuli they receive.

So, are droids capable of "thinking"? Well, according to Jedi Master Obi-Wan Kenobi in **Episode II: Attack of the Clones**:

> If droids could think, there'd be none of us here.

But, I don't think that gives us the whole picture. All of the evidence we have available from the films, television shows, comics, video games, and novels that are available seem to indicate that droids are capable of, at the very least, some basic decision-making. Droids are built with a low-level AI (artificial ***intelligence***) that drives their fundamental "personalities" and gives them "quirks" - [C-3PO](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/C-3PO) is a bit of a prim-and-proper "dandy", while [R2-D2](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/R2-D2) is more of a street-smart "rascal". However, they both make "decisions" from our first encounters with them in **Episode IV: A New Hope**. One specific example of such autonomous decision-making is after Leia gives R2 the Death Star plans and records her message for Obi-Wan, R2 dutifully enters the escape pod to jettison himself down to Tatooine.

You might be saying, *"But, that's just a programmed response to an order from the droid's master!"*

Perhaps, but consider ***C-3PO's*** actions in response to those of R2's. 3PO finds R2 just as Leia has finished her recording and disappears back into the shadows of the *Tantive IV*. 3PO has no direct interaction with Leia and receives no direct orders from anyone else to follow the little blue-and-white astromech (at least, none to which we are witness). So, why does 3PO continue to follow the smaller droid? Why does "goldenrod" try to stop R2 from getting into the escape pod ("*You'll be deactivated, for sure!*")? Why does the protocol droid eventually join the domed little droid in that escape pod and go down to Tatooine?

I submit that these are "decisions" made based on analyzing the stimuli of the environment. Perhaps they're based on pre-programmed imperatives (instincts) for self-preservation, but there must be some form of "intellectual" process that prompts 3PO into taking some sort of action. This, in my opinion, satisfies the "*ability to think*" element of the definition.

However, both the "*capacity for intelligence*" and "*ability to acquire wisdom*" are, perhaps, a bit more difficult to quantify here. Even so, we know that our favorite droid linguist is *now* fluent in over **7 million** forms of communication, but does that make 3PO "intelligent"?

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/intelligent) (*emphasis mine*):

> **intelligent** *adjective*
> /ɪnˈtel.ə.dʒənt/
> showing intelligence, or *able to learn and understand things easily*

When we *first* met C-3PO, the droid was only fluent in **6 million** forms of communication. However, after years in service to and with the Rebellion/Resistance, 3PO has increased his fluency by approximately 1 million additional forms of communication. According to a ScreenRant article about the protocol droid titled "[Star Wars: How Many Languages C-3PO Can Speak (& 9 Other Facts About The Character You Didn't Know)](https://screenrant.com/star-wars-how-many-languages-c-3po-can-speak-9-other-facts-about-the-character-you-didnt-know/)":

> By the time of what is known in-universe as the Cold War (the state of tension in the government as the First Order rose), Threepio's [Tranglang III communication module](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/TranLang_III_communications_module) got upgraded... When it was updated, Threepio went from six million-plus forms of communication to seven million-plus forms of communication...

Since the resulting increase in linguistic proficiency was apparently "just" a hardware upgrade, perhaps this doesn't *really* meet the criteria for "*able to learn*" - I bring it up here mainly to address the point for reference - but there's another situation I'd argue does. I'm thinking specifically of the time 3PO spent as the interpreter droid for Jabba the Hutt in **Episode VI: Return of the Jedi**.

The most simplistic example would be 3PO's "recognition" that Jabba had a trap door installed in the floor in front of his throne. When Luke arrives to confront the Hutt gangster, the droid tries to warn the Jedi but is cut off before getting the words out.

For a more complex yet, arguably, less direct example, 3PO had to "learn" how to behave in Jabba's palace in order to avoid being disintegrated like the previous interpreter droid. In fact, after apparently angering the crime lord when translating the bounty hunter [Boushh](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Boushh)'s demand for fifty thousand credits for Chewbacca, the droid asks, "what did I say?" Such a question carries with it the implication of an intention to ***learn*** so as to prevent making the same mistake again.

For a much better example of a droid's ability to learn, I'd actually have to refer to another droid: [IG-11](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/IG-11) from **The Mandalorian**. After [Kuiil](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kuiil) reconstructed the bounty hunter/assassin droid, the [Ugnaught](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ugnaught) reprogrammed it to function as a nurse droid instead of a killer. However, it still had to re-learn how to do pretty much *everything*, from walking to how to pick up a cup without crushing it. The lanky droid even learned to "shoo" away the small creatures skittering around the camp before putting down a heavy box to avoid squishing them.

While 3PO doesn't *always* seem to learn - especially when to "shut up" - does the droid exhibit wisdom?

Again, from the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/wisdom):

> **wisdom** *noun*
> /ˈwɪz.dəm/
> the ability to use your knowledge and experience to make good decisions and judgments

Does 3PO exhibit these characteristics? Well, this is where things can get really tricky as they rely on the observer's subjective perception of what constitutes a "good" decision or judgment. Is it one that benefits the decision-maker? Is it one that is in line with some sort of "moral" code (or pre-defined/pre-programmed set of "rules")? There are virtually infinite ways to define "good" in this context, but I'll limit it to the most basic and primitive imperative of self-preservation for this discussion.

In this context, I would argue that C-3PO is *capable* of making good decisions, but doesn't always do so. For example, the droid is *clearly* exhibits "good judgment" by trying to avoid going into Jabba's Palace in the opening scenes of **Return of the Jedi**  Even so, the droid duo still ends up going in anyway (*perhaps just poor execution?*).

Consider, however, R2-D2 (and the rest of [D-Squad](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/D-Squad)) when they were stranded on [Abafar](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Abafar) during their story arc in **The Clone Wars**. While their commanding officer, Colonel [Meebur Gascon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Meebur_Gascon), was content to stay near their crashed ship, the astromech took the initiative to get moving and try to find the group some help. While an argument could be made for both tactics, the fact that the party was in the middle of a barren wasteland with no other landmarks or beings in sight seemingly made proactively seeking help a more appropriate course of action - the "wise" choice, even though his actions directly countermanded the orders of his commander.

### ARE DROIDS *CONSCIOUS*/*SELF-AWARE*?

So, according to these definitions, I personally believe we can call droids both **sentient** *and* **sapient**. However, I *still* don't think that really gets at the *true* heart of the question. I think we need to go at least one more level and ask the question, "are droids ***conscious***?"

**Consciousness**, in my opinion, is what [L3-37](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/L3-37) and the [Droid Gotra](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Droid_Gotra) are claiming in their fight for [Droid Rights](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Droid_rights_(movement)). While an even more nebulous concept than either intelligence or wisdom, the [Cambridge Dictionary defines consciousness](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/consciousness) as:

> **consciousness** *noun*
> /ˈkɑːn.ʃəs.nəs/
> the state of understanding and realizing something

This implies not only a basic *awareness* of an entity's surroundings (sentience), the ability to intelligently react to or even manipulate that environment (sapience), but also a higher-level capacity for understanding of circumstances and how that entity is tied to what is happening around them. Another way of saying this might be "self-awareness". And, to this, I'd have to say that droids meet this standard as well.

Consider, again, our constantly complaining C-3PO when taken to the droidsmith, [Babu Frik](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Babu_Frik) and the [Spice Runners of Kijimi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Spice_Runners_of_Kijimi) to bypass the droid's programming and retrieve information from C-3PO's memory banks in **Episode IX: The Rise of Skywalker**. More specifically, consider the protocol droid's reaction to the proposed procedure:

> **C-3PO:** "If this mission fails... it was all for nothing. All we've done... all this time."

And then, just before going "under the knife", there's this rather emotional exchange (*at least, it was for me*):

> **Poe Dameron:** "What are you doing there, 3PO?"
> **C-3PO:** "Taking one last look Sir, at my friends."

This dialogue seems to indicate - to me, at least - that C-3PO is acutely aware of his own individuality and self. The beleaguered droid doesn't really *want* to undergo (yet another) [memory wipe](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Memory_wipe) but recognizes and ***understands*** that it's a necessary sacrifice - and, even more specifically, a sacrifice that cannot be made by anyone else - if the Resistance has any hope of triumphing over the Final Order and

> Emperor Palpatine.

So, in conclusion, based on all of the evidence we have available, it seems to me that droids in Star Wars™ are clearly not only **sentient** but **sapient** *and* **conscious**, as well. While I don't condone the Droid Gotra's tactics, I must admit that they have a valid point.

---

## *SIDE NOTE*

For additional reading/reference, there was a thread in **`r/philosophy`** on Reddit several years ago that discusses the comparison of these three concepts - [Consciousness vs Sentience vs Sapience](https://www.reddit.com/r/philosophy/comments/1n0ihz/consciousness_vs_sentience_vs_sapience/). While the thread itself isn't particularly illuminating, there is a link to a [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article on the nature of consciousness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness/) that's rather interesting.

Comment: might be worth including a bit re: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/AZI-345211896246498721347 from the last episode of The Bad Batch Season 1

Comment: I had considered including examples of other droids' exhibition of these traits - K-2SO, L3-37, 0-0-0, etc. (*although I had admittedly forgotten about AZI-3*) - but I was already getting a bit long-winded so decided to keep it focused on C-3PO. Even so, that ***does*** bring up an even "deeper" (*or, perhaps, "higher"*) layer to add to the discussion: **empathy**. That point is most certainly pertinent and relevant to what I perceive to be the fundamental question being asked in the OP. Perhaps I can come back and revisit my answer with more "evidence" after I've taken a little break. :P

Comment: Also, this doesn't even really touch on the question(s) that seems to be "lurking" in the OP: "*Are droids, in fact, galactic-level slaves who have long been cruelly and wickedly oppressed by their organic overlords, and should they be emancipated?*" To *this* question, I would again have to say "**yes**" (*and "**yes**"*), but that's a topic for an entirely new QA.

Answer (score 13):

Technically, droids are sentient beings. There is a droid torture area in Jabba's ship, used to give "pain" to droids. R2-D2 reacts with an alarmed noise, so it means that they have sensors for "feeling", and a way to "think".

According to the dictionary definition of the words, yes droids are sentient. They have the ability to feel and perceive things.

They are slaves to humans and other creatures in the movies, and they can be sold, bought and have their memory wiped. It's a rather strange world.

The actual answer to this question is: **sometimes.** The truth is that droids in star wars act in a sentient/non-sentient manner in different parts of the movie. After all, this is a fictional world from a fictional story.